# Post TFS 2012 upgrade project fails to compile

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tfs, visual-studio-2012

I just updated TFS from 2012 RC to 2012 RTM. The instal went just fine and everything is setup as it was. However now when I check-in files and the build process kicks off I keep getting an error relating to a missing System.EnterpriseServices.dll.  Here is the full error:

```
CSC: Metadata file 'c:\Builds\1\MySite\bin\System.EnterpriseServices.dll' could not be opened -- 'Error importing module 'System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll' of assembly 'c:\Builds\1\MySite\bin\System.EnterpriseServices.dll' -- The system cannot find the file specified. '
```

Yes I have verified the file is in the bin, as as well I have removed then re-added it. One thing I suspect here is that I see the new TFS install added .NET 4.5 to the server, where before it did not exist... maybe that's a possible cause?? The application is a C# MVC4 website set to .NET 4.0.

I have also ran the 'Repair' on the TFS install and re-installed .NET 4.5. The project compiles and runs perfectly locally.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Most of custom dlls problems comes from they are not in the right place, so try to put any custom dlls on the build server on the right place, see my answer there.

[Upgraded TFS 2008 build definitions to TFS 2012 build defs using Upgrade Template, errors when queueing builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387168/upgraded-tfs-2008-build-definitions-to-tfs-2012-build-defs-using-upgrade-templat/14389034#14389034)